# Remove space between abbreviated letters in a string column

Tags: python, pandas, uppercase, abbreviation

i have a panda dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': ['I called the c. i. a', 'the house is e. m',
 'this is an e. u. call!','how is the p. o. r going?']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I have removed the punctuations and removed the spaces between abbreviated letters:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'(?<=\b\w)\s*[ &]\s*(?=\w\b)','')
```

the output is (e.g 'I called the cia') what I would like to happen is however the following ('I called the CIA'). so I essentially like the abbreviations to be upper cased. I tried the following, but got no results

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'(?<=\b\w)\s*[ &]\s*(?=\w\b)'.upper(),'')
```

or

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'(?<=\b\w)\s*[ &]\s*(?=\w\b)',''.upper())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.Series.str.replace` allows 2nd argument to be callable compliant with requirements of 2nd argument of [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub). Using that you might first uppercase your abbreviations as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
def make_upper(m):  # where m is re.Match object
    return m.group(0).upper()
d = {'col1': ['I called the c. i. a', 'the house is e. m', 'this is an e. u. call!','how is the p. o. r going?']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'\b\w\.?\b', make_upper)
print(df)
```

output

```
                        col1
0       I called the C. I. A
1          the house is E. M
2     this is an E. U. call!
3  how is the P. O. R going?
```

which then you can further processing using code you already had

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'(?<=\b\w)\s*[ &]\s*(?=\w\b)','')
print(df)
```

output

```
               col1
0      I called the CIA
1       the house is EM
2    this is an EU call
3  how is the POR going
```

You might elect to improve pattern I used (`r'\b\w\.?\b'`) if you encounter cases which it does not cover. I used word boundaries and literal dot (`\.`), so as is it does find any single word character (`\w`) optionally (`?`) followed by dot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a function for the replace. Try this to make uppercase and replace spaces and punctuation of acronyms:

```
def my_replace(match):
    match = match.group()
    return match.replace('.', '').replace(' ', '').upper()

df['col1'].str.replace(r'\b[\w](\.\s[\w])+\b[\.]*', my_replace)
```